# Managing Sandbox & Production Changes

Tags: deployment, salesforce

I am looking quickly move changes between Salesforce Production & Sandbox. Is there any way we can know the difference between two environments i.e How many workflows, objects, email templates are modified/added in compared view.

I know we can use outbound change set but its tedious job of moving the changes and not feasible when Production is continuously being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking with the experts at two Dreamforce conferences I find the only way to get a description of an instance is to use the force.com IDE, as suggested by LaceySnr.  I've learned a couple techniques that help.

First, I no longer even attempt to use change sets.  These are time consuming to build, have no clarity as to what is really inside and sometimes just won't work.

Second, I keep at least two force.com IDE projects for each instance (test,production).  The first project has everything (check everything in the metadata component).  The second project is tiny and only has the components I want to work on.

The first project is checked into some change control system; CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial, etc. Your choice.   Using the differencing tools on this project let's you compare change sets.

But it is nearly impossible to develop using the first project because it takes too long for force.com to process even the smallest change.  This is because it processes the entire project whenever any change is made.  So, make all the code changes in the smaller project.

Then look at the ANT build tools http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm to automate the migration of changes from the smaller to larger project.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I will take that approach now. Looking forward to have some better way to manage it. I was planning to setup different Staging and Testing environment and have some automated way to move changes from Test => Staging environment and then Staging => Deployment can be done manually.

Answer (score 2):

I've not done this with workflows, but it is a method I use for code, layouts and objects: Use the force.com IDE from http://developer.force.com to setup projects for both Sandbox and Production, being sure to select all of the metadata components that you want (you'll want to include workflows for instance).

This will leave you with the contents of your projects stored inside a project directory in the IDE's workspace directory, then you can easily use a diff tool (I use the free [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) on Mac) to compare the directories, and of course drill down into files to see what changes exist.

Comment: Thanks LaceySnr! I am already using Eclipse IDE, but I am really looking to someway to automatically suggesting me the changes between Production & Sandbox without managing changes manually.